# Dropshipping for Services?

Tags: php, wordpress, ecommerce

I wanted to know if there is any software or coding language that can allow me to purchase services on the customer's behalf with a marked-up price.

I wanted to be able to sell other websites services for a marked up price in one website. They are all health clinics so I just need it to:

1. Send forms to the other party and schedule the appointments
2. Take payments on my end and send the rest to them (like drop shipping)

I'm using a WordPress and stripe. A good example of this is [Health Street](https://app.health-street.net/order/?zip=Inglewood,%20CA%2090303,%20USA), I know they are using this method because even MY clinic is listed there.

Comment: Does "sending forms to the other party" mean emailing them a PDF, sending a fax, filling out a webform...? If you're sourcing from a variety of websites and don't have APIs, you'd probably have to have a custom way of interacting with those websites, possibly with something like [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/).